# What is the right name for the variant of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic that retains the sign of the difference?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is normally defined as

$D = \max_x |A(x) - B(x)|.$

I would like to compute a variant that retains the sign of the difference between the distribution functions:

$D^\prime = A(x) - B(x) \quad\text{where}\quad x = \arg\max_x |A(x) - B(x)|.$

What is the right name of $D^\prime$?

Note that $D^\prime$ is different than
$D^+ = \max_x [A(x) - B(x)]$
and
$D^- = \max_x [B(x) - A(x)],$
which [Coberly and Lewis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02479749) describe as “one-sided” KS-statistics.

For context, the $D^\prime$ as defined above is used by [Perlman et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1100709) to profile drug-treated cultured cells. (See page 3–4 of the supplement.) They compute $D^\prime$ independently for each image feature of the sample, then standardize the $D^\prime$-values (using the mean and standard deviation of the same measurement on mock-treated samples). Correlated profiles (of standardized $D^\prime$-values) indicate drugs that have similar biological effects.

Comment: $D^{+}$ and $D^{-}$ are common names for the one-sided statistics (cf http://www.springerlink.com/content/y460k248m8w1822j/ ).  In what context does your $D'$ appear?

Comment: @whuber: Added context and comparison to $D^+$ and $D^-$ to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a variant of [Kuiper's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test) to me, although Kuiper's *V* = *D<sup>+</sup>* + *D<sup>−</sup>* ≠ *D'*.